# getting error when trying to add object in django admin

Tags: django

[error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juuCt.png)

Trace:

```
OperationalError at /admin/jobs/job/add/
no such table: main.auth_user__old
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/jobs/job/add/
Django Version: 2.0.2
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
no such table: main.auth_user__old
Exception Location: C:\Users\codering\Desktop\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute, line 303
Python Executable:  C:\Users\codering\Desktop\myenv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.0
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\codering\\Desktop\\portfolio',
 'C:\\Users\\codering\\Desktop\\myenv\\Scripts\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\codering\\Desktop\\myenv\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\codering\\Desktop\\myenv\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\codering\\Desktop\\myenv\\Scripts',
 'c:\\users\\codering\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\Lib',
 'c:\\users\\codering\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\codering\\Desktop\\myenv',
 'C:\\Users\\codering\\Desktop\\myenv\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 20 Nov 2019 10:45:27 +0000
```

This page is opening when i am trying to add an object, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

From command line